# PHP file_exist no devuelve resultado esperado

Tags: php

Estoy comprobando si existe una imagen para mostrarla en el caso de que no exista, que muestre una imagen por defecto. Para comprobarlo he probado los siguiente:

```
$imagen = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/assets/img/'.$infoUsuario["USCOD"].'.png';
echo $imagen;
if(file_exists($imagen)){
    echo "EXISTE";
}else{
    echo "NO EXISTE";
}
```

Me devuelve siempre que no existe, pero si pongo la ruta (la mostrada en el `echo $imagen`) en el navegador me muestra la imagen correctamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_exists` sirve para comprobar si existe un fichero ubicado en el servidor.

Tu estás intentando comprobar si el servidor es capaz de devolverte algo a través de una petición `http` que es algo diferente.

Para verificar si existe la imagen tienes que operaro con **rutas de ficheros válidas**. Un ejemplo:

```
$imagen = './assets/img/'.$infoUsuario["USCOD"].'.png';
if(file_exists($imagen)){
    echo "EXISTE";
}else{
    echo "NO EXISTE";
}
```

Nota que la ruta que he puesto en el ejemplo es relativa y puede que no sirva para tu caso.

Comment: Justo ahora había descubierto cual era la solución, he pecado de no investigar demasiado antes de preguntar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @AndoniAlda Son cosas que pasan, no te preocupes